# Android 'Hello world' said goodbye to me T_T

Tags: android

I followed the Android Hello world example the other day, and got it to run. I saw "hello world" on the emulator. Today I ran it again, but I don't see "hello world" anymore! I waited 5 mins, and still saw Android charging 50% and showing time.

This is how I opened the Hello world project:
at Eclipse, File>New>android project, then I selected create from existing project. It brought up my project. Then I clicked on 'Run' button..no more Hello world.

I also saw this message in red at the Console window in Eclipse when I ran the project. What does this mean?
[2011-08-04 23:25:36 - Emulator] Unknown savevm section type 95

I also went to SDK&AVD manager, and installed Android 3.2 platform. My Hello world project requires minimum 2.2 platform.

How do I get Hello world to work again?

Comment: You don't need to create new project every time. Just pick the existing one and run it. I would go into details, but i don't have it on this pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that you didn't swipe the lock and unlock the screen in the emulator. Did you swipe the green colour unlock button, then you'll be able to see the hello world application u wrote.

You can write hello world application even with android 1.5.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried that and it works. I don't remember having to unlock the screen the first time I created the hello world though. Is this something expected? I'm just curious.

Comment: I dont remember emulator loads without lock.. anyway now you know it.